German umlaut at listing settings
May I know how can the Umlaut ü (Tür) be shown in the listing settings?
I couldn't find the online examples in the listing setting.
Thanks for any help!
\documentclass[
    ngerman,
        11pt,
    %twoside,
    BCOR=8mm,
    headings=normal,
    parskip=half,
    headsepline,
    automark,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    %,captions=tableabove
    %draft
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
%
\ifluatex
 % LuaLaTeX
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 % \setmainfont{Arial}
 \usepackage{selnolig}
\else
 % PdfLaTeX
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
%
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlang1}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} 

\lstdefinestyle{myLaTeX}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=TeX,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    tabsize=2,
    morekeywords={
        lstdefinestyle,
        footnotesize,
        ttfamily,
        color,
    },
}

\lstdefinestyle{myBasic}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    escapechar={|_},
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
}

\lstset{style=myLaTeX}

%=======================================

\newcommand{\tb}{\textbackslash}
%
\newcommand{\comm}[1]{\enquote{\texttt{\tb #1}}}
%
\newcommand{\param}[1]{%
    $\langle$\textrm{\textit{#1}}$\rangle$%
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  language=HTML,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=lines
}

% Define listing settings for HTML
\lstdefinestyle{html}{ 
breaklines=true, 
postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}, 
numbers=left, 
stepnumber=1, 
numbersep=10pt, 
numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
keepspaces=true 
}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=html]
<title> Lebensmittel & mehr online kaufen, Frisch bis an die Tür! </title>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


\lstset{literate={ü}{{\"u}}1}

I'd recommend against trying to have a document compilable with both pdflatex and lualatex. There are too many differences. Anyway, for simple documents it might work.
You need some changes, though: load lmodern and fontenc only if not using lualatex and, in this case, also define the accented characters you need.
\documentclass[
    ngerman,
    11pt,
    %twoside,
    BCOR=8mm,
    headings=normal,
    parskip=half,
    headsepline,
    %automark, % <--- what's this?
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    %,captions=tableabove
    %draft
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % not outside of \ifluatex
%\usepackage{lmodern} % not outside of \ifluatex

\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
  % LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  %\setmainfont{Arial}
  \usepackage{selnolig}
\else
  % PdfLaTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
%
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{lstlang1}% not needed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{colortbl} % better pass 'table' to xcolor

\lstdefinestyle{myLaTeX}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=TeX,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
    tabsize=2,
    morekeywords={
        lstdefinestyle,
        footnotesize,
        ttfamily,
        color,
    },
}

\lstdefinestyle{myBasic}{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    escapechar={|_},
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
}

\newcommand{\tb}{\textbackslash}
%
\newcommand{\comm}[1]{\enquote{\texttt{\tb #1}}}
%
\newcommand{\param}[1]{%
    $\langle$\textrm{\textit{#1}}$\rangle$%
}

\lstset{
  language=HTML,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=lines
}

\ifluatex
\else
  \lstset{
    literate={ü}{{\"u}}1
  }
\fi

% Define listing settings for HTML
\lstdefinestyle{html}{ 
  breaklines=true, 
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}, 
  numbers=left, 
  stepnumber=1, 
  numbersep=10pt, 
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keepspaces=true 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=html]
<title> Lebensmittel & mehr online kaufen, Frisch bis an die Tür! </title>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

Be careful with too many \lstset instructions that contradict each other.
With lualatex

With pdflatex

With columns=flexible (so my eyes stop bleeding)


Thanks for your practical and clear help, how skillful you are.
